# pandas column transformation to get cumulative dollar amount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

I have dataset as below. I am trying to group them by district and find the total amount for each product. I want  to extend my calculations to find the cumulative sales amount as well as adding total sales amount in that district.

Dataset:

```
district      item       salesAmount
Arba          pen        10
Arba          pen        20
Arba          pencil     30
Arba          laptop     10000
Arba          coil       100
Arba          coil       200
Cebu          pen        100
Cebu          pen        20
Cebu          laptop     20000
Cebu          laptop     20000
Cebu          fruit      800
Cebu          oil        300
```

I could group by district and find the total amount for each product as  below

`df.groupby(['district', 'item']).agg({'salesAmount': 'sum'})` 
Results as below:

```
district      item       salesAmount
Arba          laptop     10000
Arba          coil       300
Arba          pencil     30
Arba          pen        30
Cebu          laptop     40000
Cebu          fruit      800
Cebu          oil        300
Cebu          pen        120
```

I want to order from highest amount to lowest amount for each district first.

Then add cumulative and total sales amount column as below:(per district)

```
district    item    salesAmount cumsalesAmount  totaldistrictAmount
Arba        laptop  10000       10000           10360
Arba        coil    300         10300           10360
Arba        pencil  30          10330           10360
Arba        pen     30          10360           10360
Cebu        laptop  40000       40000           41220
Cebu        fruit   800         40800           41220
Cebu        oil     300         41100           41220
Cebu        pen     120         41220           41220
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` per both columns:

```
print (df.dtypes)
district       object
item           object
salesAmount     int64
dtype: object

df1 = df.groupby(['district', 'item'], as_index=False)['salesAmount'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['district', 'item'], as_index=False).agg({'salesAmount': 'sum'})
print (df1)
  district    item  salesAmount
0     Arba    coil          300
1     Arba  laptop        10000
2     Arba     pen           30
3     Arba  pencil           30
4     Cebu   fruit          800
5     Cebu  laptop        40000
6     Cebu     oil          300
7     Cebu     pen          120
```

Then sort by both columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and last [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['district','salesAmount'], ascending=[True, False])
df1['cumsalesAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].cumsum()
df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].transform('sum')
 #alternative
 #df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['cumsalesAmount'].transform('last')
print (df1)
  district    item  salesAmount  cumsalesAmount  totaldistrictAmount
1     Arba  laptop        10000           10000                10360
0     Arba    coil          300           10300                10360
2     Arba     pen           30           10330                10360
3     Arba  pencil           30           10360                10360
5     Cebu  laptop        40000           40000                41220
4     Cebu   fruit          800           40800                41220
6     Cebu     oil          300           41100                41220
7     Cebu     pen          120           41220                41220
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first line of code gives me error as below:   `TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'`

Comment: @Lilly - What is `print (df.info())` before my solution?

Comment: ```district              19551 non-null object

item                  19551 non-null object

salesAmount    19551 non-null object```

Comment: @Lilly - I think `df1 = df.groupby(['district', 'item']).agg({'salesAmount': 'sum'})` is necessary change to `df1 = df.groupby(['district', 'item'], as_index=False).agg({'salesAmount': 'sum'})`

Comment: There are some products with salesAmount as 0 in my initial dataset. I will try to remove that and see if it works.

Comment: @Lilly - Are values in column numeric? Not necessary `df['salesAmount'] = df['salesAmount'].astype(int)`?

Comment: You are right changing the data type to int resolved the issues and I could move on with your suggestions. But I get the following error while trying to frind the `totaldistrictAmount`      ```TypeError: <class 'str'> object is not callable```   When I looked at the df.info, I could see salesAmount and cumSalesAmount as `long`...

Comment: ```df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].transform('sum')```  is giving the following error `TypeError: <class 'str'> object is not callable`. I tried ```df1 = df1.reset_index()``` adding as 3rd step in your code. But still didn't solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Lilly - it is weird errors, is possible see all your code?

Comment: Yes, I saw many examples following the same convention. Actually I am using the exact 3 steps as you mentioned. I see problem only with third line. Not sure.

Comment: @Lilly - Problem is `df1['cumsalesAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].cumsum()` ?

Comment: @jezreal, that line works. Problem is with transform line ```df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].transform('sum')```

Comment: error as below ```TypeError: <class 'str'> object is not callable```

Comment: @Lilly - It is same like `df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['cumsalesAmount'].transform('last')`

Comment: After I changed to your last code ```df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['cumsalesAmount'].transform('last')```,    I still get ```TypeError: <class 'str'> object is not callable``` error. It's weird

Comment: @Lilly - btw, is not some variable called `transform` ?

Comment: @Lilly - If still problem try `df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1['district'].map(df1.groupby('district')['salesAmount'].sum())` instead `df1['totaldistrictAmount'] = df1.groupby('district')['cumsalesAmount'].transform('last')`

Comment: Shoot... Actually my mistake.. I am working on pysaprk df and used Kolas to convert pyspark df to kolas_df and trying to use pandas functions. The issue with Kolas is `transform` function is not available. Hence I converted my pyspark df to pandas and now your code works. Should be careful while using Koalas. Thanks for all your inputs and really appreciate your time.